# Mulesoft salesforce connector getting subquery of commentcase does not display

Tags: subquery, salesforce, mule, datamapper, mule-studio

I am creating a new project where it reads data from Salesforce and pushes the data into the Google Search Appliance (GSA). In the Salesforce SOQL statement, I have a query where it gets all the comments for the case. When I use Salesforce workbench, I am able to see all the CaseBody from the CaseComment for that case. But when I use the datamapper in MULE, the CaseComment.CommentBody does not display. Is there a way to log that into a file or on the console what the Salesforce is getting back? I tried to map the CaseComment as a List, but still no luck. Is there a way to see that that Salesforce Connector is returning?

Here is the SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate, CaseNumber, Subject, InternalSubject__c, Description,
  IsClosed, POC__r.FirstName, POC__r.LastName, Owner.FirstName, Owner.LastName,
  InformationFrom__c, Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Account.Name,
  ProductName__c, ProductVersion__c, ProductProblemType__c, SubjectMatterExpert__r.Name,
  CaseProductRegion__r.Name, CaseProductModel__r.Name, CaseProductSecondaryModel__r.Name,
  CreatedBy.FirstName, CreatedBy.LastName,
  LastModifiedBy.FirstName, LastModifiedBy.LastName,
  (SELECT CommentBody From CaseComments),
  (SELECT Subject, Description FROM Tasks),
  (SELECT Subject, Headers, Textbody FROM EmailMessages)
FROM Case limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

On the input side of the equation (left side of datamapper), right click on the top level Case, click on add field. 
In the type, select Collection from the drop down. 
In the name, type CaseComments (don't press enter yet or you won't be able to add the child elements). 
Click plus on the child elements: 
Change field_0 to queryLocator of type String. (Remember to press enter after typing in queryLocator or else the name falls back to field_0). 
Click the plus again and type in done (Remember to press enter) of type String. 
Click the plus again and type in size and select type Integer. 
Now right click on the CaseComments, and add field again. 
Type Collection 
Name records (Don't press enter yet, click plus on the child elements) 
Replace field_0 with CommentBody of type String (remember to press enter) 
Replace field_1 with type of type String (Press enter) 
Now do the same for the right hand side of the data mapper 
Remember that you don't need to be at the top field, when you click the plus on the right side, it is actually Add metadata field, not just add field. 
You need to map the CaseComments from the left side to the right side. 
But you are not done yet. Just mapping the top field will not automatically map the fields underneath (needs improvement!) 
You will need to map the records from the left side to the right side also.